# Module using for creating a table

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

I want to have a 4 tables with using of module. Unfortunately I don't know why doesn't it work

```
Do[Module[{m = n, i, j}, 
    tt[m_] := Table[i/11 + j/m, {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}], tt], {n, 9, 12}]
```

For each `n` I must have a `5*5` matrix of which elements are `i/11 + j/m`.

Comment: `Table[i/11 + j/m, {m, 9, 12}, {i, 5}, {j, 5}]` will yield a list of your matrices. Note how the last three arguments are arranged.

Comment: Finally I must point to each 5*5 matrix as f[m_], for example `f[m_] := Table[i/11 + j/m, {m, 9, 12}, {i, 5}, {j, 5}]`, but as you know it doesn't work correctly again.

Comment: … \*sigh\* `Table[f[m], {m, 9, 12}] = Table[(* stuff *)]`. Probably important for you to know that we can do parallel assignment here: `{x, y} = {2, 3}` will set the two symbols to their corresponding values.

Comment: I have understood my mistake in my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/)'s comments you could use:

```
Do[
  f[m] = Table[i/11 + j/m, {i, 5}, {j, 5}],
  {m, 9, 12}
];

f[11] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \frac{2}{11} & \frac{3}{11} & \frac{4}{11} & \frac{5}{11} & \frac{6}{11} \\
 \frac{3}{11} & \frac{4}{11} & \frac{5}{11} & \frac{6}{11} & \frac{7}{11} \\
 \frac{4}{11} & \frac{5}{11} & \frac{6}{11} & \frac{7}{11} & \frac{8}{11} \\
 \frac{5}{11} & \frac{6}{11} & \frac{7}{11} & \frac{8}{11} & \frac{9}{11} \\
 \frac{6}{11} & \frac{7}{11} & \frac{8}{11} & \frac{9}{11} & \frac{10}{11} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Also see [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html), e.g.:

```
Do[
  f[m] = Array[#/11 + #2/m &, {5, 5}],
  {m, 9, 12}
];
```